# What is the advantage of proving that a function is strongly quasiconcave?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization, discrete-optimization

I have a function $f(x)$ which under certain conditions is strongly quasiconcave while under some other conditions it cannot be said whether the function is quasiconcave or not. If I am interested in finding the maxima of the function $f(x)$ then I can take the first derivative of $f(x)$ and check all of its roots. Whichever root gives me the highest value I can chose it as the maxima. So my question is why one should prove that under certain conditions the function is strongly quasiconcave (that is it has only one local maxima)? Can this proof affect the implementation of the algorithm for finding the global maxima of the function $f(x)$?

Comment: It is easier to find *one* local maximum than it is to find *all* the local maxima.

Comment: @Rahul thank you for your comment. You mean implementation wise it will be easier right? How easier will it be? Can we quantify it?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm, obviously. The most basic and fundamental algorithm, gradient ascent, is guaranteed to give you just one local maximum. There is no foolproof algorithm to find all local maxima of an arbitrary non-quasiconcave function.

Comment: @Rahul what if i have an analytical expression of the derivative of function? Even then it is not possible to get the all the roots of the derivative and subsequently all the local maximas?

Comment: What algorithm do you have in mind for finding all the roots of an arbitrary analytical expression? I don't know of any.